# How to segregate data from Flux without the underlying call again?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am working with reactive spring-boot framework and I have a flow like this in my application, (**psuedo code**):

```
Flux<String> keys; // getting flux of keys from some part of code
Flux<RedisData> response = getDataFromRedisForKeys(keys);

Flux<RedisData> responseTypeA = filterATypeResponseFromRedisDataFlux(response);
Flux<RedisData> responseTypeB = filterBTypeResponseFromRedisDataFlux(response);
Flux<RedisData> responseTypeC = filterCTypeResponseFromRedisDataFlux(response);
Flux<RedisData> responseTypeD = filterDTypeResponseFromRedisDataFlux(response);
```

Now, when I am trying to do flatMap ops on the 4 fluxes after the filter, I am seeing that data from redis is being get 4 times, what I want is that we get it once reactively and segregate it out without blocking.

Comment: Do you want to take data corresponding to A,B,C,D from redis at once and stream it?

Comment: @Jilliss yes, I want to make one call and then filter out A,B,C,D and then do their processing separately.

Answer (score -1):

getDataFromRedisForAllKeys is according to your incoming key returns the corresponding redis data needs to be yourself

You just need to search through redis for the key you need first and then filter or subscribe

You can try using the subscribe method
And process data in it
Flux result = getDataFromRedisForAllKeys(keys);

```
    result.subscribe(data -> {
        switch (data.key){
            case "A":
                //                    do something
            case "B":
                //                    do something
            case "C":
                //                    do something
            case "D":
                //                    do something
        }
    });
```

Or use the Flux filter method

```
Flux<RedisData> responseTypeA = result.filter(redisData -> "A".equals(redisData.key));
```

Comment: This answer is very dependent on who the final consumer of the data is. The subscriber is always the final consumer. So if the starter of the request is a we page going through an rest api, the final consumer is the client and you should most likely not use `subscribe`. If this is for example a `scheduled` job in server and server is the final consumer then yes `subscribe` can be used.

Comment: Yes, you can also call the Flux `filter` method and return the Flux object after filtering, which also matches the answer to the question

Comment: @Jilliss, may be I was not clear enough, I am doing like that only, but then when I am trying to do flatMap on those 4 filtered fluxes, redis call is being done 4 times. That is the issue, Let me update this in question also.